# Construct and evaluate an equation in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, eval, soa

I'm trying to come up with a good way to have a WCF web service construct an equation that can then be passed back to a client, which would then evaluate the equation by plugging the numbers into the appropriate locations.

We have a form that has numerous types of fields, but all of which are ultimately used to calculate section subtotals, and then a final total.  We're trying to keep to SOA practices, so we don't want the javascript or UI C# to make any decisions about how calculations should be done, but we want to try to avoid having to hit up the web service every single time a field on the form changes.  So we're trying to come up with a way to have the calculation equation still dictated by the web service, but then provided back to the client in such a way that it can then be evaluated and have the appropriate properties plugged into it.  We can even use the javascript eval() for this.

The other complication to this is that we may have 3rd parties that choose to have all calculations handled by the web service, so they would just pass a request object and let it determine the amounts every time.  Our thoughts for this is to basically have a second operation contract that would utilize the first to determine the appropriate equation, and then basically just evaluate it, similar to how our client UI code would.  I was thinking of having the equation be some kind of array which would include arithmetic enumerations between property names which could then be serialized if we want, but the whole thing is still very much a work in progress, and I wanted to put all this out there early on to see if I could get some opinions.

Thanks in advance for any advice/suggestions/criticism you may be able to provide.

Comment: I don't deal too much with the web side of .NET, but it sounds like you're looking for "expression trees" which can be used to build up an expression that's defined by a bunch of objects. You could possibly serialize the expression tree to have the server evaluate it. Not sure, but here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: That might work so long as I can get it back to the client from the web service. I'll have to take a more in depth look at it. I was also looking at something like [http://ncalc.codeplex.com/](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I'll have to keep that project in mind for something else... :)